# Could you please help me shorten these sentences as much as possible?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, word-order

I am trying to write instructions for an editor to make changes in some video, and I need to give the details in a succinct, yet understandable way. I would like to know what it is possible to remove from the sentences while still retaining a basic sense of grammaticality.

for example:

- Blur out the cleavage of the brunette in the brown jacket.
- Blur out the brand name of the bottle on the table.

Can I shorten the two of them to these...

- Blur "the brunette in the brown jacket" cleavage.
- Blur "the bottle's brand name" on the table.

Are there any other suggestions on what parts of speech could be deleted for abbreviated instructions?

Comment: This is an [_exact_ duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374687/could-you-explain-the-difference-between-these) of a post that I edited earlier this week.

Comment: How about “Blur all cleavage and brand names.”

Comment: the video is too long and I need to mark the parts that need to edited.

Comment: @Tiberius This question has been asked previously and marked off-topic. Posting the exact same question as another (or possibly yourself) will not yield different results.

Comment: I just need some help in English, isn't that the goal of this site?
by the way, I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: Yes, we are here to help, but we do not do the work for you. If you have a part of the sentence you wish to remove, we can tell you if it will work or not but will not work for you. You have also not shown any work of your own. What research have you done?

Comment: @Tiberius The goal of the site is more focused and narrower than "help with English". There are many types of questions of English we are not set up to answer, for example interpretation of poetry, or proof reading resumes, or suggesting topics for masters theses for grad students in English, or ideas on how to write the next great American novel. This question is falls under the umbrella of "types of questions we don't answer". As Hank says, that's not going to change, no matter how you word it, or whether you ask it 7 times. You'll need to find a different site.

Comment: @Dan Bron Could you please suggest me another site that could me in this matter?

Comment: I'm personally not aware of any, sorry. I am a native speaker so I don't need others to proof-read my English. All I can suggest is go back to the tool that led you to EL&U (this site) and use that same tool to find another site. For example, if you used Google to find EL&U, use Google to find other English-related sites.

Comment: @Dan Bron Being a native speaker doesn't mean you know everything about the language, and this a proof, you all are trying to avoid answering my questions, and being rude instead of helping. anyways, thank you.

Comment: @Tiberius Let me put it a different way: I am not offering my native speaking status as *evidence* of not using sites to proofread my English, I am telling you, as an outright fact, that I do not use sites to proofread my English. If it helps you to ignore the reason behind that behind that is I'm a native speaker, by all means, do so: it doesn't change the facts. Now, on to "trying to avoid answering your questions": I don't need excuses. They're off-topic, just as questions about cooking would be. Your assumption that the site does or should answer any and all questions of English is wrong.

Comment: The two sample sentences you give are clear and immediately understandable. If you shorten them, it will probably  take the reader a bit longer to understand them, and would thus slow down the editing process

Comment: @ab2 Thank you. you are the only serious person here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something that I like to call "telegraphic style."  Here's what it looks like with your examples:

> Blur out cleavage of brunette in brown jacket.
>
> Blur out brand name of bottle on table.

So far, all I've done is remove articles.  But true telegraphic style sometimes removes other words too.

If you give a time stamp for each edit, you can omit more, I would think.  Also, you can do some grouping and you can replace "of" by a comma.  For the bottle, wouldn't it be clearer for your editor if you name the bottle by brand name, such as Heinz or ketchup?

> Blur out the following:
>
> 1:05 Cleavage, brunette in brown jacket
>
> 1:17 Brand name, ketchup bottle